# Data don't send to database

Tags: express

```
   async function sendData(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5001/it/question', {
        question,
        question_body,
        code,
      });
      alert('Question added');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed');
    }
  }
```

Controller

```
const ict_question = asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {
    const{question,question_body,code} = req.body;
    if(!question || !question_body){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("All Fields are required");
    }
    const question_send = await questionss.create({
        question,
        question_body,
        code,
        
    });
    res.json(question_send);
})
```

Route

```
router.route("/question").post(ict_question);
```

I couldn't find an error.but after fill the form data doesn't send to database.sendData function is also working properly.but looks like route doesn't call.

Comment: First of all, let us know the routing file , plus where you import the route file(like app.use(router) or app.use("/it", router)) and what are you using as database. Probably your route strategy is wrong. Additionally you should add axios header that `Content-Type` for send request with body.

Comment: app.use("/it",require("./routes/subjectRoutes")); I used like this @myrn

Comment: Share your express file with us. Maybe you're stuck with any middleware or something. Are you gettin any API response from axios post?